# How to get full text of tweets using Tweepy in python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am collecting tweets using tweepy api and I want the full text of the tweets. Referring to examples in https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/974, [tweepy Streaming API : full text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319243/tweepy-streaming-api-full-text?rq=1) and [Tweepy Truncated Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050289/tweepy-truncated-status/43968932) I tried this using the extended_mode. But I am getting an error saying **AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'full_text'**.

From the examples above I know that If the tweet is not more than 140 characters, then have to just get the text as usual. However, these examples were for StreamListener and I am not using a StreamListener. How can I use the try catch blocks like in [tweepy Streaming API : full text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319243/tweepy-streaming-api-full-text?rq=1) and solve the error I get and get the full_text of the tweets? How should I modify my below code?

> getData.py

```
import tweepy
import csv

# Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    # Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

    # authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []

    # make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200)

    # save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    # save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    # keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print
        "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

        # all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200, max_id=oldest, include_entities=True,
                                       tweet_mode='extended')

        # save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        # update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print
        "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    user = api.get_user(screen_name)
    followers_count = user.followers_count

    # transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode("utf-8"), 1 if 'media' in tweet.entities else 0,
                  1 if tweet.entities.get('hashtags') else 0, followers_count, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count]
                 for tweet in alltweets]


    # write the csv
    with open('tweets.csv', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id", "created_at", "text", "hasMedia", "hasHashtag", "followers_count", "retweet_count", "favourite_count"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass

def main():
    get_all_tweets("@MACcosmetics")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the cursor to parse the tweets in extended mode [tweepy documentation 3.6.0 https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/tweepy/latest/tweepy.pdf ] and change your usages of
.text to .full_text

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id='MACcosmetics', tweet_mode='extended').items():
    print(status.full_text)
```

Answer (score 3):

in the end, this is what worked for me:

```
status = tweet if 'extended_tweet' in status._json: status_json = status._json['extended_tweet']['full_text'] elif 'retweeted_status' in status._json and 'extended_tweet' in status._json['retweeted_status']: status_json = status._json['retweeted_status']['extended_tweet']['full_text'] elif 'retweeted_status' in status._json: status_json = status._json['retweeted_status']['full_text'] else: status_json = status._json['full_text'] print(status_json)'
```

Comment: WELL DONE!! If anyone looking to get tweet by tweet id, then this is the piece of code that REALLY WORKS