# Tweepy doesnt print out the entire Tweet if I stream

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I can't get entire tweets to print out. The problem is that I already included 
`tweet_mode=extended` into the request, but still can't get the whole tweet text to be displayed

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import tweepy
import zugangsdaten
import sys

auth=OAuthHandler(zugangsdaten.consumer_key, 
zugangsdaten.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(zugangsdaten.access_token, 
zugangsdaten.access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API (auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        non_bmp_map=dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000,sys.maxunicode+1),0xfffd)
    print(status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))      
def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 420:
        #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
        return False

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream=tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth,listener=myStreamListener,tweet_mode="extended")
myStream.filter(track=['Donald Trump'])
```

*improved formatting*

Current Output: RT @twitter_user: Deranged Donald is at back at it again. Deranged Donald can do things like this and it’s not even the top of the news, beca…

I would like to have the whole tweet displayed, instead of just 140 chars.

Comment: tweet_mode does not apply to the streaming API. You need to access the extended_tweet.full_text element of the Tweet in the streaming API.

Comment: @AndyPiper as a total noob in python: How can i do that ?

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319243/tweepy-streaming-api-full-text

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me:

```
status = tweet if 'extended_tweet' in status._json: status_json = status._json['extended_tweet']['full_text'] elif 'retweeted_status' in status._json and 'extended_tweet' in status._json['retweeted_status']: status_json = status._json['retweeted_status']['extended_tweet']['full_text'] elif 'retweeted_status' in status._json: status_json = status._json['retweeted_status']['full_text'] else: status_json = status._json['full_text'] print(status_json)'
```